# replace for-loops with (py)spark native logic for successive process step tracking

Tags: apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark

**Main Question**: How to convert this particular for-loop-based logic into PySpark logic that scales?

I am modeling a process where I track the progress on produced items through a series of five successive steps. I receive the following data, describing when an item reaches a given process step:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|item_ID|brand|model|country|     step1|     step2|     step3|     step4|     step5|
+-------+-----+-----+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|      1|    A|    X|     US|2024-02-05|2024-02-07|2024-02-09|2024-02-11|2024-02-13|
|      2|    A|    Y|     US|2024-02-01|2024-02-04|2024-02-09|2024-02-12|2024-02-15|
|      3|    B|    Z|     CA|2024-02-06|2024-02-09|2024-02-10|2024-02-11|2024-02-16|
|      4|    B|    Z|     CA|2024-02-08|2024-02-09|2024-02-12|2024-02-13|2024-02-14|
|      5|    C|    W|     US|2024-02-05|2024-02-06|2024-02-07|2024-02-09|2024-02-10|
|      6|    C|    W|     IT|2024-02-03|2024-02-07|2024-02-12|2024-02-14|2024-02-16|
+-------+-----+-----+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The outcome is a time series. for each groupBy of Country, Brand and Model, it indicates the number of items residing at a particular step, per day (here filtered to the two Canadian Items for displaying purpose):

```
+----------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|      Date|Country|Brand|Model|step1|step2|step3|step4|step5|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|2024-02-06|     CA|    B|    Z|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|2024-02-07|     CA|    B|    Z|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|2024-02-08|     CA|    B|    Z|    2|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|2024-02-09|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    2|    0|    0|    0|
|2024-02-10|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    1|    1|    0|    0|
|2024-02-11|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    1|    0|    1|    0|
|2024-02-12|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    1|    1|    0|
|2024-02-13|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    0|    2|    0|
|2024-02-14|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    0|    1|    1|
|2024-02-15|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    0|    1|    1|
|2024-02-16|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    0|    0|    2|
|2024-02-17|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    0|    0|    2|
|2024-02-18|     CA|    B|    Z|    0|    0|    0|    0|    2|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Observe how the two Canadian items move through steps 1-5 over time according to the dates of each step in the input.

The best I could come up with is a for-loop based logic below which won't scale on the spark cluster, and takes inadequate amounts of time to compute even a small subset of the data.

How can I transform the input into the output using PySpark native code **without for-loops**?

Thanks for any help!

Working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# generate test data
data = {
    'item_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'brand': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'model': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'W', 'W'],
    'country': ['US', 'US', 'CA', 'CA', 'US', 'IT'],
    'step1': ['2024-02-05', '2024-02-01', '2024-02-05', '2024-02-08', '2024-02-05', '2024-02-03'],
    'step2': ['2024-02-07', '2024-02-04', '2024-02-07', '2024-02-09', '2024-02-06', '2024-02-07'],
    'step3': ['2024-02-09', '2024-02-09', '2024-02-10', '2024-02-12', '2024-02-07', '2024-02-12'],
    'step4': ['2024-02-11', '2024-02-12', '2024-02-11', '2024-02-13', '2024-02-09', '2024-02-14'],
    'step5': ['2024-02-13', '2024-02-15', '2024-02-16', '2024-02-14', '2024-02-10', '2024-02-16'],
}
df_pd = pd.DataFrame(data)
steps = ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5']
# prepare datatypes for pyspark & create spark dataframe
for col in steps:
    df_pd[col] = pd.to_datetime(df_pd[col]).dt.date
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)

# Define the start and end date for February 2024, generate time range of interest
start_date = '2024-02-01'
end_date = '2024-02-29'
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

# replace the following _bad_ code by proper pyspark logic without for-loops
result_list = []
for step in ['step1', 'step2', 'step3', 'step4', 'step5']:
    for country in df_pd.country.unique():
        for brand in df_pd.brand.unique():
            for model in df_pd.model.unique():
                for date in date_range:
                    count = int((
                                (df_pd[step] <= date) &
                                (df_pd.country == country) &
                                (df_pd.brand == brand) &
                                (df_pd.model == model)
                                ).sum())
                    result_list.append((date.to_pydatetime().date(), step, country, brand, model, count))
explicit_steps = spark.createDataFrame(result_list, ["Date", "Step", "Country", "Brand", "Model", "Count"])

pivoted_df = explicit_steps.groupBy("Date", "Country", "Brand", "Model").pivot("Step").sum("Count")
result_df = (pivoted_df.withColumn("step1", F.col("step1") - F.col("step2"))
             .withColumn("step2", F.col("step2") - F.col("step3"))
             .withColumn("step3", F.col("step3") - F.col("step4"))
             .withColumn("step4", F.col("step4") - F.col("step5"))
             )
```

I tried various approaches to remove the forloops in order to turn this into a scalable code that runs with big data on a spark cluster. But so far did not succeed.

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what are you trying achieve Ex : Country CA Brand B Dated 2024-02-07 there is nothing in the source data in step1 but count is 1 in transformed data. Similarly Country CA Brand B Dated in 2024-02-08 step 1 has count 2 count is 1 in source data in step1 but count is 2 in transformed data. Lack of clarity what is expected

Comment: i refined the outcome to "indicate per day, for each combination of Country, Brand, Model the number of items residing at a particular step".

for your first example: item ID3 is at step1 on Feb 6. it stays there on Feb 7. On Feb 8 it continues to stay at step 1, but gets joined by item ID4, so there is two of them now. On Feb 9, both ID3 and ID4 progress to step2. and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that looks promising with test data. once verified with real data, I may rate this as the answer.
`df_spark` is defined in the opening question.

```
logger.info("starting...")

group_cols=["country", "brand", "model"]
key_cols = ['date', "country", "brand", "model"]
step_columns = ["step1", "step2", "step3", "step4", "step5"]


# Step 1: "Explode" the dataframe to convert the 5 step columns into one column
# 1.1 Creating an array of structs for each step and its respective date
steps_explosion_expr = explode(array([
    struct([lit('1').alias('step'), col('step1').alias('date')]),
    struct([lit('2').alias('step'), col('step2').alias('date')]),
    struct([lit('3').alias('step'), col('step3').alias('date')]),
    struct([lit('4').alias('step'), col('step4').alias('date')]),
    struct([lit('5').alias('step'), col('step5').alias('date')]),
])).alias("steps")

# 1.2 make exploded df
df_exploded = df_spark.select(
    col('item_ID'),
    col('brand'),
    col('model'),
    col('country'),
    steps_explosion_expr
).select(
    'item_ID', 'brand', 'model', 'country', 
    'steps.step', 'steps.date'
)


# Step 2: Group by date, country, brand, and model; count items in each step; then pivot
logger.info("pivoting...")
df_pivot = df_exploded.groupBy(*key_cols).pivot('step').count()

# 2.2: Fill missing pivot values with 0
df_filled = df_pivot.na.fill(0)

# Renaming columns for clarity (due to the struct handling)
df_filled = df_filled.withColumnRenamed("1", "step1") \
                   .withColumnRenamed("2", "step2") \
                   .withColumnRenamed("3", "step3") \
                   .withColumnRenamed("4", "step4") \
                   .withColumnRenamed("5", "step5")

# Apply the cumulative sum to each step column per group (via windowSpec)
logger.info("accumulating counts...")
df_cumsum= df_filled
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(*group_cols).orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
for step_col in step_columns:
    df_cumsum = df_cumsum.withColumn(step_col, F.sum(step_col).over(windowSpec))

logger.info("substracting cumulative counts between steps")
df_correct = df_cumsum
# here happen the substractions, probably the for-loop must be replaced by explicit code per column according to business logic
for i,column in enumerate(step_columns[:-1]):
    df_correct = df_correct.withColumn(column,col(column)-col(step_columns[i+1])) 


# Generate a DataFrame with all dates in the desired range
logger.info("generating all combinations of dates & groups...")
start_date = datetime.date(2024, 2, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2024, 2, 20)
date_range = [start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((end_date-start_date).days + 1)]
# the dummykey join replaces a crossjoin that proved to take extremely long on the test setup
dates_df = spark.createDataFrame(date_range, "date").select(col("value").cast("date").alias("date")).withColumn("dummykey",lit(1))
groups_df = df_spark.select(*group_cols).distinct().withColumn("dummykey",lit(1))
all_combinations_df  = groups_df.join(broadcast(dates_df), "dummykey", "inner").drop("dummykey")

# Left join this with your original DataFrame
logger.info("joining existing data with all possible key combinations")
joined_df = all_combinations_df.join(df_correct, key_cols, "left")

# Fill missing values with the last known value, ignoring nulls. think like "in excel: fill down"
logger.info("down-filling count values to previously unpupulated date rows...")
filled_df = joined_df.select(
    *key_cols,
    *[last(col(c), ignorenulls=True).over(windowSpec).alias(c) for c in step_columns]
)

# fill the remaining null values appearing between the start date and the first step1 of each group with zero
logger.info("filling remaining nulls ahead of first counts...")
result = filled_df.fillna(0)
```